# Формат строки предаваемой командной строке

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Не работает команда

```
if (i==1) 
    tPipe=_popen("logman create counter ch -c ""\\Процесс(ch)\\""Рабочее множество"""" -f tsv", "rt");
```

выдает ошибку "Недопустимый путь к счетчикам множества".

Comment: А тут случаем не лишняя закрывающая кавычка после пути? И почему она русскими буквами? Как на англоязычной машине это будет работать?

Comment: не понял какая скобка как я понимаю с++ не нравится пробел в рабочее множество

Comment: выручайте ребята обязательно нужно командной строке передать

Comment: Строки, в командной строке, содержащие пробелы, должны быть заключены в кавычки. [Консольные команды Windows NT](http://www.emanual.ru/download/www.eManual.ru_3417.html)

Answer (score 1):

Похоже строка не правильно описана. Вот некоторые спец. символы:

```
\n - новая строка    
\r - возврат каретки  
\" - двойная кавычка  
\\ - косая черта (обратная)
```

Например, строка

```
"файл "c:\temp\1.txt" не найден"
```

описывается:

```
"файл \"c:\\temp\\1.txt\" не найден"
```